# Safest way to force close a file descriptor

Tags: linux, file-descriptors, unmounting, gdb

Sometimes you need to unmount a filesystem or detach a loop device but it is `busy` because of open file descriptors, perhaps because of a `smb` server process.

To force the unmount, you can kill the offending process (or try `kill -SIGTERM`), but that would close the `smb` connection (even though some of the files it has open do not need to be closed).

A hacky way to force a process to close a given file descriptor is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/323180/4471415) using `gdb` to call `close(fd)`.
This seems dangerous, however. What if the closed descriptor is recycled? The process might use the old stored descriptor not realizing it now refers to a totally different file.

I have an idea, but don't know what kind of flaws it has: using `gdb`, open `/dev/null` with `O_WRONLY` (edit: an comment suggested `O_PATH` as a better alternative), then `dup2` to close the offending file descriptor and reuse its descriptor for `/dev/null`. This way any reads or writes to the file descriptor will fail.

Like this:

```
sudo gdb -p 234532
(gdb) set $dummy_fd = open("/dev/null", 0x200000) // O_PATH
(gdb) p dup2($dummy_fd, offending_fd)
(gdb) p close($dummy_fd)
(gdb) detach
(gdb) quit
```

What could go wrong?

Comment: One thing that could happen, you could loose buffered data that should have been written to that file descriptor. That of course depends on application.

Comment: In general, I'd rather just terminate the program (and tell any service manager controlling it not to restart it automatically) instead of making it suddenly get an EOF on one of its files. What if it had read the first 10 characters of the line `RunAsUid=12345` in a config file and you do the /dev/null thing right after that?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick if I could get it to return an access error or an I/O error would that solve the issue you raised?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - I haven't verified it, but the reason I open `/dev/null` with `2` (= `O_WRONLY` is so that reads should fail with `EACCESS` instead of `EOF`

Comment: Yes, opening it write-only would make reads fail, but that flag is 1. 2 is read-write.

Comment: oops. I had meant `O_WRONLY`. I'll edit that.

Comment: @afuna please update your question to use `0x200000` (`O_PATH`). that's the way to go if you want an "opaque" file descriptor (on which not only reads and writes, but also ioctl, lseek, ftruncate and fchmod will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddling with a process with `gdb` is almost never safe though may be
necessary if there's some emergency and the process needs to stay open
and all the risks and code involved is understood.

Most often I would simply terminate the process, though some cases may
be different and could depend on the environment, who owns the
relevant systems and process involved, what the process is doing,
whether there is documentation on "okay to kill it" or "no, contact
so-and-so first", etc. These details may need to be worked out in a
post-mortem meeting once the dust settles. If there is a planned
migration it would be good in advance to check whether any processes
have problematic file descriptors open so those can be dealt with in a
non-emergency setting (cron jobs or other scheduled tasks that run
only in the wee hours when migrations may be done are easily missed if
you check only during daytime hours).

### Write-only versus Read versus Read-Write

Your idea to reopen the file descriptor `O_WRONLY` is problematic as not
all file descriptors are write-only. John Viega and Matt Messier take a
more nuanced approach in the "Secure Programming Cookbook for C and C++"
book and handle standard input differently than standard out and
standard error (p. 25, "Managing File Descriptors Safely"):

```
static int open_devnull(int fd) {
  FILE *f = 0;

  if (!fd) f = freopen(_PATH_DEVNULL, "rb", stdin);
  else if (fd == 1) f = freopen(_PATH_DEVNULL, "wb", stdout);
  else if (fd == 2) f = freopen(_PATH_DEVNULL, "wb", stderr);
  return (f && fileno(f) == fd);
}
```

In the `gdb` case the descriptor (or also `FILE *` handle) would need to
be checked whether it is read-only or read-write or write-only and an
appropriate replacement opened on `/dev/null`. If not, a once read-only
handle that is now write-only will cause needless errors should the
process attempt to read from that.

### What Could Go Wrong?

How exactly a process behaves when its file descriptors (and likely also
`FILE *` handles) are fiddled behind the scenes will depend on the
process and will vary from "no big deal" should that descriptor never be
used to "nightmare mode" where there is now a corrupt file somewhere due
to unflushed data, no file-was-properly-closed indicator, or some other
unanticipated problem.

For `FILE *` handles the addition of a `fflush(3)` call before closing
the handle may help, or may cause double buffering or some other issue;
this is one of the several hazards of making random calls in `gdb`
without knowing exactly what the source code does and expects. Software
may also have additional layers of complexity built on top of `fd`
descriptors or the `FILE *` handles that may also need to be dealt with.
Monkey patching the code could turn into a monkey wrench easily enough.

### Summary

Sending a process a standard terminate signal should give it a chance
to properly close out resources, same as when a system shuts down
normally. Fiddling with a process with `gdb` will likely not properly
close things out, and could make the situation very much worse.

Comment: Thanks! The point of using `O_WRONLY` is specifically to cause errors - we don't want the process to get an incorrect `EOF`, like @MarkPlotnick commented above.

Comment: but sure is fun bleeding the process of their handles and seeing them slowly die off, I do that on windows all the times with process explorer.

Comment: I just wanted a simpler way of yanking a file handle from unix and CLOSING it, muahaha  (I'm almost sure the process explorer is injecting a debugger somewhat similar to gdb to do that, I mean, you could kill the handle from the kernel side)

Answer (score 2):

> open /dev/null with O_WRONLY, then dup2 to close the offending file descriptor and reuse it's descriptor for /dev/null. This way any reads or writes to the file descriptor will fail.

If you dup a descriptor to `/dev/null`, any writes will not *fail*, but *succeed*, and the reads will *succeed* and return 0 (eof).

This may or may not be what you want.

On linux, you can also open a file with flags = 3 (`O_WRONLY|O_RDWR` aka `O_NOACCESS`) which will cause any read or write to fail with `EBADF`.

The file will only be available for ioctls -- which brings up a danger not talked about in the other answer and comments: reads and writes are not the only operations done on file descriptors. (what about `lseek` or `ftruncate`?).

**Update:**

I found something better than the undocumented `O_WRONLY|O_RDWR`: `O_PATH = 010000000 / 0x200000`. According to the open(2) manpage:

> ```
> O_PATH (since Linux 2.6.39)
>      Obtain a file descriptor that can be used for two  purposes:  to
>      indicate a location in the filesystem tree and to perform opera-
>      tions that act purely at the file descriptor  level.   The  file
>      itself  is not opened, and other file operations (e.g., read(2),
>      write(2), fchmod(2), fchown(2), fgetxattr(2), mmap(2)) fail with
>      the error EBADF.
>
>     The  following operations can be performed on the resulting file
>      descriptor:
>
>     *  close(2); fchdir(2) (since Linux 3.5); fstat(2) (since  Linux
>         3.6).
>
>     *  Duplicating  the  file  descriptor (dup(2), fcntl(2) F_DUPFD,
>         etc.).
> ```

Comment: *On linux, you can also open a file with flags = 3 (`O_WRONLY|O_RDWR` aka `O_NOACCESS`)*  Ooof.  That directly [violates the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):  "Applications shall specify exactly one of the first five values (file access modes) below in the value of `oflag`"

Comment: I did not claim that was portable ;-) It's an obscure hack, only used in `lilo` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: linux has its own flavour of POSIX, its fine